# Can't manage to change Gatling indicators bounds when editing `gatling.conf`

Tags: gatling

I want to change the range of chart in Gatling output report, so I changed the `gatling.conf`like here:

```
  charting {
    #noReports = false       # When set to true, don't generate HTML reports
    maxPlotPerSeries = 1000 # Number of points per graph in Gatling reports
    #useGroupDurationMetric = false  # Switch group timings from cumulated response time to group duration.
    indicators {
      lowerBound = 500      # Lower bound for the requests' response time to track in the reports and the console summary
      higherBound = 1500    # Higher bound for the requests' response time to track in the reports and the console summary
      percentile1 = 50      # Value for the 1st percentile to track in the reports, the console summary and Graphite
      percentile2 = 75      # Value for the 2nd percentile to track in the reports, the console summary and Graphite
      percentile3 = 95      # Value for the 3rd percentile to track in the reports, the console summary and Graphite
      percentile4 = 99      # Value for the 4th percentile to track in the reports, the console summary and Graphite
    }
  }
```

But My scenario report output didn't change:
[image]

Where should I change my config?

Answer (score 0):

Works for me (tested with Gatling 3.4.1). I suspect you're missing the `gatling` root node.

```
gatling {
  charting {
    indicators {
      lowerBound = 500
      higherBound = 1500
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Gatling indicators with custom bounds]